# how to re-run method when you re-visit screen in react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have wrote a method and tried calling that method in componentDidMount() ,componentWillMount(), render() methods but no methods runs again in react-native. I want to re-run that method every time screen is visited.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/), you can use `import { NavigationEvents } from 'react-navigation';`, then in your render method:

```
 return (   
        <View>   
          <NavigationEvents
            // onWillFocus={payload => console.log('will focus',payload)}
            // onDidFocus={payload => console.log('did focus',payload)}
            // onWillBlur={payload => console.log('will blur',payload)}
            // onDidBlur={payload => console.log('did blur',payload)}
          />  
          <View></View>
        </View>
```

Reference: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-events.html

Comment: Glad can help, accepting the correct answer would be appreciated